# Javascript click not works on Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to click this button on this page https://froala.com/demo-editor-new/

[image]

It works fine if I click using my mouse, but it does not work when I run this code from the Chrome Dev Tools `document.querySelector('#moreMisc-1').click()`

Any idea what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 3):

The click handler first checks if the event is a real user gesture and then shows the menu. It is achieved with event.isTrusted property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Any javascript artificial dispatching of events generates events with isTrusted set to false. It is only true in genuine user actions.

Comment: I did not know this, very interesting. Learn something new every day.